# Logging out of Flutter app doesn't go back to login page

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to authenticate users in my app, and login/signup, and logging out works correctly when I logout from the home page directly following the login page, but doesn't work when I logout from a settings page routed from the home page.

It is logged out on firebase, but the page won't go back to the login page immediately calling signout unless I press the back button on the appbar.

This is my signout function:

```
abstract class BaseAuth {
  Future<void> signOut();
}

Future<void> signOut() async {
  return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
}

final BaseAuth auth;
final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

_signOut() async {
  try {
    await widget.auth.signOut();
    widget.onSignedOut();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

In my root page, I have:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED:
        return _buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      case AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN:
        return new LoginSignUpPage(
          auth: widget.auth,
          onSignedIn: _onLoggedIn,
        );
        break;
      case AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN:
        if (_userId.length > 0 && _userId != null) {
          return new HomePage(
            userId: _userId,
            auth: widget.auth,
            onSignedOut: _onSignedOut,
          );
        } else return _buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      default:
        return _buildWaitingScreen();
    }
  }
```

So if the authenticaiton status is not logged in, it should return back to the LoginSignUpPage.

I'm not sure why this delay is happening.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have a hard time understanding which page is presented when you log out from e.g., your settings page. And what would the scenario be to reach the else{} part in your AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN?

Comment: The first page displayed when entering the app is the LoginSignUpPage, and when logged in, the user is directed to the HomePage. On the HomePage menu, there is a setting icon, which routes to the SettingsPage. Right now, a logout button from the HomePage redirects back to the LoginSignUpPage when logged out, but a logout button from the SettingsPage does not redirect back to the LoginSignUpPage unless I press the back button.

Comment: try adding `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/"));` as the last line in your `_signOut()`. This will pop all screens stacked on top of first screen in your stack.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So adding `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/"));` as the last line in `_signOut()` solved the issue.

It simply pop all screens stacked on top of first screen in your stack.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me

Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(context);

Answer (score 0):

Try using PushReplacement, Even I use it when I get the issue and I don't have time to fix it, yeah it can be used as fix for the issue too!

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement or pushNamedReplacement(Screen to navigate);
```